# Load and Save file using serialize in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, loading, file-handling

I created a code where properties were written as:

```
namespace ContactManagement
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public int Id{get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

        public Contact()
        {

        }
        public Contact(int id, string name, byte age, DateTime date, string city)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Age = age;
            this.Date = date;
            this.City = city;
        }
    }
}
```

after writing this, I wrote a code where file handling was written:

```
namespace ContactManagement
{
    public class ContactDB
    {
        string fileAddress = @"e://ContactDB.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ContactDB dbObj = new ContactDB();
            List<Contact> lstContact = new List<Contact>(){
                new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
                new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
                new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
                new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
                new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
                new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
                new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
                new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
            };
            dbObj.Save(lstContact);
            dbObj.Load();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public void Save(List<Contact> lstContact)
        {
            FileStream wfs = new FileStream(fileAddress, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            XmlSerializer serialobj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContactDB));
            serialobj.Serialize(wfs, lstContact);

            wfs.Close();
        }
        public List<Contact> Load()
        {
            List<Contact> listofContact = new List<Contact>();
            FileStream rfs = new FileStream(fileAddress, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            XmlSerializer newserial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContactDB));
            string line;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileAddress))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine())!= null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
            return listofContact;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that after compiling it, I am receiving an error which is: There was an error generating the XML document.

Comment: Does it say what the error is?

Comment: This is the error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There was an error generating the XML document.

Comment: Is there an InnerException? It should give you more information. When it says 'There was an error', there should be information about what the error is and where it's occurring. Have you tried to put breakpoints in? Or wrap the save code in a try/catch, `throw ex;` and put a breakpoint on that.

Comment: I did. I tried try and catch as well as finally. The error it produced was again the same. It is catching the count of the list which is 8. But it is not displaying the list and the error displayed is : There was an error generating the XML document.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a Serializer for `ContactDB` but are passing an instance of `List<Contact>`. Unless the former extends the latter this is not going to work...

You need to either create a Serializer for `List<Contact>` and continue passing your lists to the serializer:

```
public void Save(List<Contact> lstContact)
{
    FileStream wfs = new FileStream(fileAddress, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    XmlSerializer serialobj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Contact>));
    serialobj.Serialize(wfs, lstContact);
    wfs.Close();
}
```

OR add a Property for your list to `ContactDB` and pass your db to the serializer.

```
public void Save(ContactDB db)
{
    FileStream wfs = new FileStream(fileAddress, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    XmlSerializer serialobj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContactDB));
    serialobj.Serialize(wfs, db);

    wfs.Close();
}
```

Here's a solution that works for me:

```
        List<Contact> lstContact = new List<Contact>(){
            new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
            new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
            new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
            new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
            new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
            new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
            new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
            new Contact(){ Name="hello", Age=10, Date=new DateTime(2017,03,12), City="test"},
        };
        String xml;
        using (MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Contact>));
            ser.Serialize(str, lstContact);
            xml = Encoding.Default.GetString(str.ToArray());
        }
        List<Contact> lstContact2;
        using (MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml)))
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Contact>));
            lstContact2 = (List<Contact>)ser.Deserialize(str);
        }
```

Comment: even when i created serializer for contact in which properties were made, I am facing the same error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There was an error generating the XML document.

Comment: @ApoorvaSharma I've expanded the answer to provide examples for what you can do.

Comment: public void Save(List<Contact> lstContact)
        {

            FileStream wfs = new FileStream(fileAddress, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            XmlSerializer serialobj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Contact>));
            try
            {
                serialobj.Serialize(wfs, lstContact);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                wfs.Close();
            }
        } This is what I Wrote. But the error now is in XML document (2, 2)

Comment: @ApoorvaSharma That should have worked. I've added a full solution. Please compare with that.

Comment: @ApoorvaSharma I've copied the method from your comment and it works for me. Where exactly are you getting that new error?

Comment: I am not able to deserialize the file. I have removed that line. and now the code is working fine. But what I don't get is why deserialize is not working in my code.

Comment: @ApoorvaSharma The Load method you posted makes no sense. It doesn't even use the Serializer. Can you try mine and post what exactly the problem is? (Symptoms, Error, Line where the error happens)

Comment: File is not being created at the first place when I used your method.

Comment: Got IT!! Thank you for your help. Earlier I forgot to call the Save function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

retVal = (List)xml.Deserialize(ReadFs );

Comment: i tried your above code. and is showing me the error while taking deserialize  in a separate function. can we take serialize and deserialize in different functions? @kempeth